# Windows/Vagrant:There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`,

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I vagrant box file that was packaged on a Macbook. I transferred the file into Windows on my Surface Book and getting some permission error.

To fix this, other people suggested to enable virtualization and disable Hyper-V, which I have done already. After I tried this, I'm still getting the same problem, my VM can't be power on.

Please also see my attached screen capture. 
[image]

```
jacky@DESKTOP-F0E0NKI MINGW64 ~/vm
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "47187f36-41f2-4941-9f1d-3930bc011f0f", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: RawFile#0 failed to create the raw output file /Users/yuh8/vm/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

jacky@DESKTOP-F0E0NKI MINGW64 ~/vm
$
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't remove `.vagrant`, always use `vagrant destroy` or `vagrant destroy -f` to start from the scratch.
2. Disable HyperV.
3. Reinstall Virtualbox (repair installation).
4. Reinstall Vagrant (repair installation).
5. Go to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv` → right click on `VBoxDrv.inf` → select <kbd>Install</kbd>.
6. Execute `sc start vboxdrv`
7. Execute `vagrant up`.